# Login to google bookmarks service using cmd-line curl

Tags: curl

Since google bookmarks don't have API exposed, I have to do it manually.

I tried first regularly, with using clientAuth and passing token in subsequent request but it doesn't work (the same code works for other exposed services, like picasa or contacts).

I used Temper Data plugin for Firefox to record posted data in order to replay it. Here is my code in AutoHotKey script:

```
cmd = curl -k -s https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=bookmarks&passive=true&nui=1&continue=https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l&followup=https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l 
cmd = %cmd% -c cookie.txt -v -d "continue=POSTDATA=continue=https`%3A`%2F`%2Fwww.google.com`%2Fbookmarks`%2Fl&followup=https`%3A`%2F`%2Fwww.google.com`%2Fbookmarks`%2Fl&service=bookmarks&nui=1&dsh=-8806623507079762088&timeStmp=&secTok=&GALX=7dKFR_6fPME&Email=MYEMAIL`%40gmail.com&Passwd=MYPASS&signIn=Sign+in&asts=" 

out := Run(cmd)
FileAppend, %out%, out.html
```

The google returns

```
Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on
```

altho I did set *-c cookie.txt* option

Whats wrong ? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247006/php-how-to-save-cookies-for-remote-web-pages) post it should work I think.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter c is where cookie goes.
For input it's  -b.

Use both for a dialog:

```
Curl -b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt http://[...]
```