# How to get cookie from remote webpage using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

When I get a response from a page, it gives a response data but if I want to get cookie of the session which is set by page, how can I get it with PHP cURL?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');`

Comment: may help this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247006/save-cookies-for-remote-web-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways(may be more) you can do this.

Using the cookie file:

```
$cookie_file = 'e:/demo/cookies.txt';
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
```

Using from the header that is responded back with html source from curl.

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
// this is returning the http response header along with html
```

You'll find the cookies there under the `Set-Cookie:` header for second example.

By the way, I assume you know how to handle curl. If you don't here are [few helps](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).